# How to make a timer count down to a time you assign for it python

Tags: python, canvas, time, tkinter, timer

I am trying to make a program which counts down to a specific time. In this program I have assigned the time when I want it to say click me but I am having trouble figuring out how to make a timer which counts down to that time. This is the code I currently have:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

x = datetime.today()
y = x.replace(day=x.day, hour=1, minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta_t = y-x

secs = delta_t.seconds+1

def hello_world():
    label = Label(tk, text="CLICK NOW", font=('Times', 45), fg='blue')
    label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

t = Timer(secs, hello_world)
t.start()

tk.mainloop()
```

If anyone has any suggestions to have the timer countdown to the specified time it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: How would incorporate it into the code and keep the same concept I have now. I have tried to use date time but it hasn't been successful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189554/countdown-clock-0105

Comment: I read through the question but it still doesn't have the answer

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you do?

```
secs = delta_t.total_seconds() + 1
```

Instead of

```
secs = delta_t.seconds + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to make it work more efficiently but how do I make it countdown to that time

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple timer made using tkinter that you can incorporate into your code: just use it as `.after()`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
msg = Label(root, text = str(60))
msg.pack()
def timer():
    msg['text']=str(int(msg['text'])-1)
    root.after(60, timer) # continue the timer
root.after(60, timer) # 60 ms = 1 second
root.mainloop()
```

This is the most basic concept of making a timer using tkinter. And it will be very useful.

Comment: Where would I incorporate the .after()

Comment: Depends on what you want to do...you posted code doesn't work well

Comment: Ok. The thing I was trying to accomplish with the posted code was to make it say click me at the specified time. But I need to advance it and make it say 10,9,8,7..... before it says click me. Then at 0 which is the 60th second of the minute it says the specified time.